# How to center card elemnt on page both vertically and horizontally with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to center the card on the page, but it just does not center vertically

I've tried every idea on stack and otherwise without a solution that works

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
  <img class="card-img-left" src="" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Yousif Alnajjar</h5>
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#" class="card-link">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#" class="card-link">Letter of Application</a></li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#" class="card-link">CV</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vwoJMo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bootstrap 4 utility classes for **flex-box to center the items both horizontally as well as vertically.**

Create a div wrapper around the card and add the flex-box utility classes `d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center`

- `d-flex` used to set the container as `display: flex`.
- `align-items-center` used to centers the item vertically.
- `justify-content-center`used to centers the item horizontally.

**Set the height of the wrapper div**, so that we can center it vertically, for demo purposes i have set it to `min-height: 100vh;`

```
.vh-100 {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center vh-100">
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
  <img style="float:left" src="" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Yousif Alnajjar</h5>
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#" class="card-link">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#" class="card-link">Letter of Application</a></li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#" class="card-link">CV</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Working Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NVQaxj)